# Strings getting attached when i add them from table into Arraylist

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-room

I'm adding strings from table to ArrayList to add them into Drodown Menu , something like this :

```
@Query("SELECT name FROM tbl_data WHERE label LIKE :query ")
List<String> getSelectedName(int query);

ArrayList<String> dropDownTitle;

try {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        dropDownTitle = (ArrayList<String>) dataDao.getSelectedName(Integer.parseInt(titleLabel));
        tvDisc.setText(titleText);
        for (int y = 0; y < dropDownTitle.size();) {
            data.add(String.valueOf(dropDownTitle));
            y++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated: " + e);
    }
```

it become like this :

[image]

but i want it to look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're adding same item (array, instead of items of array) over and over.

```java
for (int y = 0; y < dropDownTitle.size();) {
            data.add(String.valueOf(dropDownTitle));
            y++;
        }
```

Should be something like this:

```java
for (String dropDownItem: dropDownTitle) 
{ 
    data.add(dropDownItem);
}
```

or

```java
for (int y = 0; y < dropDownTitle.size(); y++) {
            data.add(String.valueOf(dropDownTitle.get(y)));
}
```